# json schema validate empty array of objects

Tags: json, jsonschema

```
var schema = {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "data"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "$id": "#/properties/data",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "id",
        "name",
        "description",
        "groups"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/id",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
          "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/name",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "description": {
          "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/description",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "groups": {
          "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/groups",
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/groups/items",
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/groups/items/anyOf/0",
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                  "id",
                  "name",
                  "description"
                ],
                "properties": {
                  "id": {
                    "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/groups/items/anyOf/0/properties/id",
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "name": {
                    "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/groups/items/anyOf/0/properties/name",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "description": {
                    "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/groups/items/anyOf/0/properties/description",
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

And I have json result either:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Contacts",
        "description": "Pre-installed contacts management for your account.",
        "groups": []
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Update Container Sub Type 913",
        "description": "I'll calculate the virtual SQL bus, that should circuit the FTP sensor!",
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "tech",
                "description": "tech description group"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And when I validate json schema, the second - valid, the first - invalid.
How can I resolve it to do both as valid?

Comment: A little simplification, side from the answer: you don't need all those `$id`s.  They just specify the locations, so they're implicit.

Comment: Your schema is fine.  See https://jsonschema.dev/s/s3K9o.  I suspect something is wrong with the validator you're using.

Comment: Whatever tool you used to generate this schema did a terrible job. I highly suggest you don't use it anymore. Also, I second that your schema is correct. The validator you are using has a bug.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [JSON Schema Specification](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#name-minitems) version 2020-12, it's possible to validate the minimum amount of items inside an array. Just use the property "minItems".

You can write something like this:

```
{
    "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/groups",
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 1,
    "items": {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

edited: ** This does not answer the question **

#### Option 1 : Validators and Json-schema versions

edited: deleted wrong information.

#### Option 2 : discard the `anyOf`

The problem might be the `anyOf`: it means *one or more of these* , therefore, group cannot be empty. See the [docs on json-schema.org](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html) for more info.

But why do you need an `anyOf` , when you only have **one** type of items ?
Try :

```json
 {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",

  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "data"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "$id": "#/properties/data",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "id",
        "name",
        "description",
        "groups"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/id",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
          "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/name",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "description": {
          "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/description",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "groups": {
          "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/groups",
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
                "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/groups/items/anyOf/0",
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                  "id",
                  "name",
                  "description"
                ],
                "properties": {
                  "id": {
                    "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/groups/items/anyOf/0/properties/id",
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "name": {
                    "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/groups/items/anyOf/0/properties/name",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "description": {
                    "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/groups/items/anyOf/0/properties/description",
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So you can get rid of the `anyOf` constraints , and validate an empty array as it is allowed by default.

#### Option 3 : conditional schemas

If your validator doesn't accept an empty array of `anyOf`s (some does) , There might be a possibility to work something out with *conditional structures* like `if`, `then` ... see [reference](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html).
something in the lines of :

- if array size is > 0 then apply the "anyOf" sub-schema

Please let us know how you solved this issue.

Comment: No draft specifies that if a property is an array and is required that it needs to be non-empty. The issue you linked is about allowing the `required` keyword to be empty.

Comment: Also, while the reset of the answer isn't wrong, it is irrelevant because the schema is valid (other than the misuse of `$id`s). This is clearly a bug with the validator they are using.

Comment: Thanks @JasonDesrosier , I stand corrected. that explains a lot about most validators accepting empty arrays. May I ask, does it means that an array of `anyOf` can be empty too , despite the `anyOf` definition of 1+ ?

Comment: All the keywords that are defined to be an array of schemas, including `anyOf`, are defined to be non-empty.